# using the driver definiton created in eclipse

Tags: java, database, eclipse

once we create a driver definition in eclipse .
uing windows>preferences>data management>driver definitions .
How do we access that in our current project and use the connection?

Comment: Are you talking about [Eclipse DTP](http://wiki.eclipse.org/Data_Tools_Platform_Project) ? Because this can not be used in Java Projects.

Answer (score 0):

You have created the driver definitions for Eclipse DTP, this is a plugin which is used to develop databases and SQL-scripts or other plugins and project-types can use it. For more information take a look at following wiki:

[Data Tools Platform Project](http://wiki.eclipse.org/Data_Tools_Platform_Project)